# Bash script inputting multiple variables

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I use a simple shell script to block IP addresses that just substitutes my input (an IP) for a variable in an iptables, IPFW, etc. (depending on which platform on) command, but they all basically follow this format:

```
read -p "IP to Block: " ip

ipfw add deny ip from $ip to any
```

Is it possible to simply execute, sequentially, a group of user-defined variables. For example, three IP addresses, and have the script execute, basically, three times for each of the variables, but limit my input to a single prompt (being asked to input one time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to do something like this:

```
for ip in $@; do
    ipfw add deny ip from $ip to any
done
```

I'm not sure if that's the exact usage of `ipfw`, but `$@` is every word in a command except the first, so it would work with:

```
your-script-name 1.2.3.4   1.3.4.5   1.4.5.6
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. For IPFW, as long as each variable prints as a single IP address for each instance of the command, then this should suffice for the level of firewall administration that the script is intended to cover.

Comment: You can use it with read with prompt also, in the script `read -p "IPs to Block (separate with space): " ips` and then `for ip in $ips; do ...` instead. And then run it without arguments.